# Count users from table 2 in request to table 1

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have table with positions

```
tbl_positions
   id position
    1 Driver
    2 Lobby
    3 Support
    4 Constructor
```

and in other table i have users

```
tbl_workers
  id   name   position
   1   John   2
   2   Mike   3
   3   Kate   2
   4   Andy   1
```

i do request of positions

```
SELECT position FROM tbl_positions
```

but i also need to show how many workers are assigned to each position i tried to do separate request

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_workers WHERE position = 2
```

but cannot display all together in table cannot bind number of users to position.

How can i make join this queries into one, so it also show positions without workers assigned?

Answer (score 1):

join and group by

```
SELECT p.id, p.position, count(*) FROM  tbl_positions as p
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.position=p.id
group by p.id, p.position
```

Comment: It does not work could you explain it? what actually count(*) does?

Comment: join creates a single data set from the two tables by matching w.position to position.id. group by creates a group of rows for each unique value of p.id and p.position, count(*) counts the number of rows in each group.